# How do I make a link hover when putting the cursor over other element of the row

Tags: css, hover

So I'm editing a wordpress theme. By default when I insert a link it changes of color, I put a hover on the whole column to lower it's opacity and make it look transparent but what I want is that when I put the link on any part of the row, the text changes its color.

So this is how it looks.

```
.col-md-3:hover {
opacity:0.7;
    }

.col-md-3 a:hover {
color:#34c663 !important;
    }
```

But that changes the link cokor just when I put the cursor on it I tried to put it like this.

```
    .col-md-3:hover {
    opacity:0.7;
    color:#34c663 !important;
        }
```

But... then the color of the link doesn't even change neither when I put the cursor on the column or on the text. What can I do?

EDIT:
Thank you guys, that was easier than I thought lol.

Comment: Can you recreate your issue by putting it to https://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Do you want to change color of `.col-md-3` and `a` inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example 1: Change opacity of column and color of link on column hover**

```
.col-md-3:hover {
    opacity:0.7;
}

.col-md-3:hover a {
    color:#34c663;
}
```

**Example 2: Change opacity of column on hover and only change color of link if it is hovered**

```
.col-md-3:hover {
    opacity:0.7;
}

.col-md-3 a:hover {
    color:#34c663;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to change the link color when hovering the column?

```
.col-md-3:hover a {
  color: #34c663;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lyc4gead/